# how to use in angular a react component

Tags: reactjs, angular

I need to use react 17.0.2 components in an angular 15.2.9 app, I followed this tutorial:
https://thalava.com/how-to-use-react-web-components-in-angular; as far I use the simple react component described in the tutorial everything works, with the real component starting the development server I get this error:

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './?ngResource' in SigninComponentWrapper.tsx
```

this is my SigninComponentWrapper.tsx:

```
import {
 AfterViewInit,
 Component,
 ElementRef,
 EventEmitter,
 Input,
 OnChanges,
 OnDestroy,
 Output,
 OnInit ,
 SimpleChanges,
 ViewChild,
 ViewEncapsulation
 } from '@angular/core';

 import * as React from 'react';
 import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import  SignIn from '../../../../assets/reactComponents/Pages/SignIn'
 const containerApp = "AppContainer"
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-signin',
 template:`<span #${containerApp}></span>`,
 styleUrls: [''],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
 })
 export class SignInWrapperComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy,AfterViewInit {
 @ViewChild(containerApp, { static: true }) containerRef!:ElementRef;

 constructor() { }
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
 ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.containerRef.nativeElement);
 }
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 this.render();


 }

 private render() {


/* ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <div>
                <CustomReactComponent counter={counter} onClick={this.handleDivClicked} />
            </div>
        </React.StrictMode>
        , this.containerRef.nativeElement); */

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <div>
  <SignIn />
  </div>
  </React.StrictMode>

    , this.containerRef.nativeElement);
 }


 ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Maybe it is just  a configuration problem ; I need some advice to shed some light on this problem

Answer (score 0):

to fix the error I declared the wrapper component as standalone